# Removing empty lines from CSV file

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I am having a CSV file in following format:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
,,,,,,,,,
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
```

And I need to remove all the empty lines from the data using notepad++.
Once I tried to using the replace function, with following parameters:
Find What: \r\n,+\r\n
Replace With: \r\n

Following result is obtained:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,
```

Why is it so?
What is wrong with regex used?
Please advise.

Comment: What is not working? It isn't relacing anything, or it is replacing to much, etc.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use a regex for a CSV file.

Comment: And why the Java tag?

Comment: Gives following result:
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,

Comment: @siju - See, your regex works on each line.. So, it replaces the new line character of the lines which are not empty as well

Comment: @WhoAmI - Is there any way to identify all blank lines?

Comment: @siju - if(!line.matches("\\d+"){ your regex here}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will notice that you are actually removing every 'alternate' empty lines. Try something like this instead:

```
^,+$
```

And replace with nothing.

`^` matches the beginning of the line while `$` matches the end of the line.